# Does XPath support WHERE clause?

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

how can I apply WHERE clause for xpath expressions?
Example:

```
<users>
    <user>
       <name>membersound</name>
       <age>52</age>
    </user>
    <user>...
</users>
```

I can check for existence eg:

```
exists(//ns1:users/ns1:user[ns1:name='membersound'])
```

How can I do the following?:

```
SELECT age WHERE name='membersound'
```

Comment: If you want to write with the same syntax, then go with Xquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is already represented by your `[ns1:name='membersound']` [predicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-predicates). To get the age, just append `/ns1:age` to your XPath expression:

```
//ns1:users/ns1:user[ns1:name='membersound']/ns1:age
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can select it..

```
//users/user[name = 'membersound']/age
```